# OpenCV image show int OpenMP parallel for

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, qt-creator, openmp

Hello I'm trying to display an image at every step of my cycle, but does not work. Here is what I have created, any ideas?

```
 #pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 1;i < blur_range; i += 2)
{


    int percent;
    float ratio = (j)/(float)blur_range;
    percent = ratio*100;
    cout << percent <<"%\n";
   // printf("%3d%%", percent );
    blur(m_img,m_img,Size(i,i));



       #pragma  omp sections
        {
            #pragma omp critical
            {
            dst = Mat::zeros(500,500 , 0 );
            imshow( "Loading..",dst );
            }
        }
  j+=2;
}
```

Comment: Where is `j` defined? And describe how doesn't it work.

Comment: j defined, before a cyrcle `int j(0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your display is only refreshed upon a "waitKey()". For example, use "waitKey(1)" to wait 1 millisecond for a keypress. Within that time, your GUI can be refresher. I also believe you will run into memory issues and threading problems, because upon showing your data might be lost and overwritten by the next iteration. Writing to a display simultaneously is bad practice and will segfault.
Look into GTK treading (gdk_leave_thread, etc) or QT threading (emit signals, etc).